# form.currentstate.validate() failing - Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I need some help with this. My task is to pick the location along with the address and submit it. But for some reasons, the _addPointKey.currentState.validate() is always giving false.

I have a TextFormField for taking the address, a location preview container, a button to open the google_map_location_picker and finally a button to submit the data. All these fields are declared inside a form with _addPointKey key.

Form validation does work, i.e. if the fields are empty, it does show in red that the fields can't be empty. But still, I have some problem with submitting the whole formData. The textFormField becomes null.

I have used google_map_location_picker package for picking the location. Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _addPointKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Map<String, dynamic> formData = {
    "address": null,
  };

Widget _addressField() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Address of the Collection Center",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                filled: true),
            maxLines: 4,
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return "Address is required";
              }
              return '';
            },
            onChanged: (String value) {
              formData["address"] = value;
            },
            onSaved: (String value) {
              formData["address"] = value;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _locationPreview() {
    return (_pickedLocation != null)
        ? Container(
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            )),
            child: GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _pickedLocation.latLng,
                zoom: 14.4746,
              ),
              markers: Set.from(newMarkers),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            child: Text(
              "Location is required.",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          );
  }

  Widget _locationButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      onPressed: () async {
        LocationResult result = await showLocationPicker(
          context,
          < API key>,
          initialCenter: LatLng(31.1975844, 29.9598339),
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          layersButtonEnabled: true,
        );
        setState(() {
          _pickedLocation = result;
          _addPointKey.currentState.save();
          newMarkers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("newId"),
            draggable: false,
            position: _pickedLocation.latLng,
            onTap: null,
          ));
        });
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.location_on,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Text(
            (_pickedLocation == null) ? 'Locate on Map' : 'Change Location',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _addLocationButton() {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget, MainModel model) {
      return model.managingCenter
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                print(_addPointKey.currentState.validate());
                if (!_addPointKey.currentState.validate() ||
                    _pickedLocation == null) {
                  print(formData);
                  return;
                }
                _addPointKey.currentState.save();
                Map<String, dynamic> successInfo =
                    await model.addCenter(model.token, formData);
                if (successInfo["success"]) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => FutureBuilder(
                              future: model.fetchCenter(model.token),
                              builder: (context, authResultSnapShot) {
                                return authResultSnapShot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting
                                    ? SplashScreen()
                                    : CollectionPoints(model);
                              })));
                } else {
                  print("Something went wrong");
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        offset: Offset(2, 4),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        spreadRadius: 2)
                  ],
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Color(0xfffbb448), Color(0xfff7892b)]),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text('Add the Location',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            );
    });
  }

  void _addPoint() {
    showBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Form(
              key: _addPointKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _addressField(),
                    _locationPreview(),
                    _locationButton(),
                    _addLocationButton()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the TextFormField validator function you must return null, it indicates the field has correct value and there are no errors. Returning anything other than null will indicate that the field has an invalid value, i've shared the corrected code of the validator function.

```dart
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                filled: true),
            maxLines: 4,
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return "Address is required";
              }
             // return ''; this is causing you the error you must return null
                return null; // this is correct 
            },
            onChanged: (String value) {
              formData["address"] = value;
            },
            onSaved: (String value) {
              formData["address"] = value;
            },
          ),
```

Comment: You just saved me from the debugging of the next 3 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to create a confirm password on your flutter.
'showSnackBar' bottom pop-up to alert users for errors.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjXLd.png

```
  var _password = '';
  var _confirmPassword = '';

  // this will called 'onTap'
  void signUpUser() async {
    if (_password != _confirmPassword){ // you can add your statements here
      showSnackBar(context,
          "Password does not match. Please re-type again.");
    } else {
      FirebaseAuthMethods(FirebaseAuth.instance).signUpWithEmail(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
        context: context,
      );
    }
  }

 // Insert inside your build()
                          // to you password field.
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              _password = value;
                            },

                          // to your confirm password field.
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: confirmPasswordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              _confirmPassword = value;
                            },
                      // add this to your Sign-up button
                      onTap: signUpUser,
```